# How do I decide which which oscillation frequency and capacitors to use with a boost converter?

Tags: capacitor, inductor, datasheet, boost

I'm working on a few projects where I'll be driving about 8 WS2812B LEDs on a 5V rail with an ATTiny85 (I think the whole circuit is going to draw about .5A; I'm using .75A for my calculations).  I'm planning to power this with a lithium ion battery with a nominal voltage of 3.6 volts.

I need to boost the voltage to 5V.  I'm considering using the [XC9142B50DMR-G](https://www.torexsemi.com/file/xc9141/XC9141-XC9142.pdf) step-up converter to do this.

On page 11 of the datasheet (an image is included below), they have a reference implementation and specs for the other components.  There seem to be two options for the oscillation frequency: 1.2MHz and 3.0MHz.  I can't figure out why I'd prefer one frequency over the other.

One difference appears to be a lower supply current.  What does that mean (and if it's an advantage or a disadvantage)?  Are there other reasons I'd prefer one frequency to the other?

They also have 2 recommended capacitors but mouser doesn't have them in stock.  Can I use any ceramic capacitors that are 10uF and at 10V and an X7T dialectric?

Here's the reference circuit and BOM specs:
[image]

Comment: The inductor has nothing to do with the switching frequency; that's internal to the chip and I can't find anything in the datasheet about how to select it--it might be an option when you order the chip.

Comment: @Hearth, ohhhhhhh!  Thanks!!  Well, I suppose my questions are still still roughly the same.  I'll update the question.  Thank you!

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 Okay, maybe "nothing to do with" was an oversimplification, but the datasheet does mention an internal oscillator used to generate the switching frequency.

Comment: Yes f is internal and L=dt*V/dI external

Answer (score 1, accepted):

High frequency PWM choices  means there are good reasons for these options and one must be aware of requirements for;

-cost, of components, qty, size, performance, EM unintended interference, switching loss, temperature rise trade offs when pushing power out to the limits that constrain these.

Unless you have these requirements, it may not matter to you but L affects dI/t for a given voltage.

But as in life there are tradeoffs with size, efficiency and unintended emissions.

Answer (score 1):

> I can't figure out why I'd prefer one frequency over the other.
>
> ...
>
> One difference appears to be a lower supply current. What does that mean (and if it's an advantage or a disadvantage)? Are there other reasons I'd prefer one frequency to the other?

Actually I cannot say anything about the "supply current vs switching frequency" thing. But the only thing I can say is "The higher the switching frequency, the smaller the power inductor". Which means that higher switching frequency helps saving more space.